# Copying string literal stored by a pointer into array of strings (C language)

Tags: c, arrays

This is closely related to an [earlier question I asked.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44619699/printing-array-of-strings-without-pointers-in-c-language)

To simulate the operation of a program I'm coding, I'm trying to get the following snippet to work. I need to add strings declared as `const char*` (such as "Eta" below) into a two-dimensional array `char[][]` (such as {"Alpha", "Gamma", "Epsilon"}). Here's one of my several attempts:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
        char lines[4][10] = {"Alpha", "Gamma", "Epsilon"};
        const char *p = "Eta";
        strcpy(lines[4], p);
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                printf("%d\n", i);
                printf("%s\n", lines[i]);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

This results in a "stack-smashing" error report, which is apparently related to buffer overflow, but which I suspect has another meaning here.

While I've tried to research the difference between char[] and char*, I haven't found a method that worked. Can someone explain where I'm mistaken?

Comment: `char lines[4][10] =` --> `char lines[5][10] =` or `strcpy(lines[4], p);` --> `strcpy(lines[3], p);`

Comment: So you still don't read a C book, SO is not a tutorial site.

Comment: ... or `strcpy(lines[3], p);`

Comment: Comment out `// strcpy(lines[4], p);`  Does the output make sense?  Now code `strcpy(lines[3 /* not *4/], p);`

Comment: @Retired Ninja Jeez, so it was just an indexing error? Well now I feel stupid.

Comment: @Stargateur Not to put too fine a point on it, but I've been reading Chapter 13 of K.N. King's book over and over.... I'm not trying to abuse the site.

Comment: @Chris don't worry, you are not the first and won't be the last to index out of range.

Comment: @Chris Oh, never mind.

Comment: @Chris  It is interesting what were other your attempts?:)